# count the number of files in archive in java

Tags: java, file, count

I am trying to count the  number of files in archive . The problem that my code  count all entities including folders ( for example if I have complex directory but only one file in it I  cant validate my archive). I use method size().

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import ru.cntp.eupp.roster.Notification;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Enumeration;

/*
 * @author dfaevskii
 */
@Dependent
public class ZipValidator {

     public void validate(Path pathToFile) throws IOException {

         ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(pathToFile.toFile());

         if (zipFile.size() != 1 && zipFile.size() != 2) {
             throw new InvalidZipException("The number of files in archive is more than  2");
         } 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `entries()` method to get an `Enumeration` of the `ZipEntry`-s in the zip-file, and check each one to see if it `isDirectory()`:

```
int countRegularFiles(final ZipFile zipFile) {
    final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    int numRegularFiles = 0;
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        if (! entries.nextElement().isDirectory()) {
            ++numRegularFiles;
        }
    }
    return numRegularFiles;
}
```

Comment: I used this and declared my ZipFile object with `new ZipFile(file, Charset.forName("Cp437"));` to deal with accents (I had a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED` error before that).

Answer (score 4):

> I use method size().

That is the issue. `size()` returns the number of **all** entries in the zip file. To count the number of entries without directories, you need to iterate the entries and check whether its a directory or not:

```
...
int count = 0;
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> zipEntries = zipFile.entries();
while (zipEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry entry = zipEntries.nextElement();
    if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
       count++;
    }
}
...
```

See also

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#isDirectory